# JSON not Displaying content in Spinner

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I encountered a problem. I do not understand where my code is wrong, I have 4 spinners, all of them display the same JSON file. All four things are the same. But only one of them does not show anything. In your opinion, where is the problem with this code?

The `URL_AllUniversity` Work Correctly. But I do not understand what the problem is...
Also better to give you a Screen of what I See: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fV4t.jpg)
And, this is my `University` URL
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbFWN.jpg)

```
[ { "University": "دانشگاه آيت ا... العظمي حائري ميبد" }, { "University": "دانشگاه اراک" }, { "University": "دانشگاه اردکان" }, { "University": "دانشگاه اروميه" }, { "University": "دانشگاه اصفهان" }, { "University": "دانشگاه الزهرا(س)" },...
```

This is my Java Code:

```
    public class FormActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner spinnerStudy,spinnerUnited,spinnerCity,spinnerUniversity;
ArrayList<String> AllStudy,AllUnited,AllCity, AllUniversity;

String URL_AllStudy = "http://192.168.1.103/android_login_api/helper/AllStudy.json";
String URL_AllUnited = "http://192.168.1.103/android_login_api/helper/AllUnited.json";
String URL_AllCity = "http://192.168.1.103/android_login_api/helper/AllCity.json";
String URL_AllUniversity = "http://192.168.1.103/android_login_api/helper/AllUniversity.json";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);

    AllStudy = new ArrayList<>();
    AllUnited = new ArrayList<>();
    AllUniversity = new ArrayList<>();
    AllCity = new ArrayList<>();


    spinnerStudy = findViewById(R.id.spinner_AllStudy);
    spinnerUnited = findViewById(R.id.spinner_AllUnited);
    spinnerUniversity = findViewById(R.id.spinner_AllUniversity);
    spinnerCity = findViewById(R.id.spinner_AllCity);


    loadSpinnerDataStudy(URL_AllStudy);
    loadSpinnerDataUnited(URL_AllUnited);
    loadSpinnerDataUniversity(URL_AllUniversity);
    loadSpinnerDataCity(URL_AllCity);


    spinnerStudy.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


        String all_study =  spinnerStudy.getItemAtPosition(spinnerStudy.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),all_study, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        // DO Nothing here
    }
    });

    spinnerCity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            String all_city =  spinnerCity.getItemAtPosition(spinnerCity.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();



            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),all_city, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            // DO Nothing here
        }
    });

    spinnerUniversity.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            String all_university =  spinnerUniversity.getItemAtPosition(spinnerUniversity.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),all_university, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            // DO Nothing here
        }
    });

    spinnerUnited.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


            String all_united =  spinnerUnited.getItemAtPosition(spinnerUnited.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),all_united, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            // DO Nothing here
        }
    });


}




private void loadSpinnerDataUnited(String URL_AllUnited) {


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_AllUnited, new Response.Listener<String>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {


            try {

                ArrayList<String> AllUnited = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    AllUnited.add(new String(jsonobject.getString("United").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));


                }
                spinnerUnited.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(FormActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, AllUnited));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }

    });

    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

    private void loadSpinnerDataCity (String URL_AllCity) {


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_AllCity, new Response.Listener<String>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {


            try {

                ArrayList<String> AllCity = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    AllCity.add(new String(jsonobject.getString("City").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));


                }
                spinnerCity.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(FormActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, AllCity));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }

    });

    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void loadSpinnerDataUniversity (String URL_AllUniversity) {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_AllUniversity, new Response.Listener<String>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {


            try {


                ArrayList<String> AllUniversity = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    AllUniversity.add(new String(jsonobject.getString("University").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));

                    Toast.makeText(FormActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
                spinnerUniversity.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(FormActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, AllUniversity));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }

    });

    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void loadSpinnerDataStudy(String URL_AllStudy) {


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_AllStudy, new Response.Listener<String>() {


            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                try {

                    ArrayList<String> AllStudy = new ArrayList<>();
                    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        AllStudy.add(new String(jsonobject.getString("Study").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));


                    }
                    spinnerStudy.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(FormActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, AllStudy));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }

        });

        int socketTimeout = 30000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You remove the encoding from this line

```
 AllUniversity.add(new String(jsonobject.getString("University").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
```

and make it like this

```
 AllUniversity.add(new String(jsonobject.getString("University")));
```

Comment: Thank You, I Realize My Problem When getting log from my response in University spinner, I realized In JSON file Was Set before the symbol `[`
Another symbol...The browser automatically deleted it and displayed the file safely... Finally, I edit my JSON file... Thank you AGAIN...

Comment: Also, Your recommendation is correct, but I use special characters in Spinner (Persian language)
That's why I wrote this

Comment: Awesome @haj . Happy coding